# How to use osgeo.Warp function in python and replace bash command?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I want to write the following python code without the bash command:

```
    # warp coordinates of each tile - to correct the origin of the tif files
    for file in tqdm(file_list, desc='warp'):
        bashCommand = "gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4647 -overwrite " + file + ' ' + file[:-4] + '.tif'
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()
```

I have been trying, but I can not find a working solution. Here is my attempt to solve this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
input_file = 'input_file_name_string'
output_file = 'output_file_name_string'
input_file = gdal.Open(input_file)
gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, xRes=5, yRes=5)
dst = None
```

My ultimate goal is to resolve the error 'Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution.' and correct the NS resolution with the warp function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this (copied and modified from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py) seems to create a new GeoTIFF

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
ds1 = gdal.Open('base.tif')
dstDS = gdal.Warp('python.tif', ds1)
dstDS=None
```

It may be enough for turning the y pixel size into negative. Have a try.